# Swiper in hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

I have trouble with swiper slider. We have 2 hidden slides on page, 1st visible working fine, but others dont works, all slides have full width, and dont scroll.

```
 var swiper2;
$(document).ready(function(){
        swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container-height-mod2', {
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
            slidesPerView: 1,
            paginationClickable: true,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            breakpoints: {
                // when window width is <= 960px
                767: {
                    slidesPerView: 1
                }
            },
        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Add to options

```
{
observer: true,
observeParents: true
}
```